504 Server Error: Gateway Timeout for url: https://asia-docker.pkg.dev/v2/_catalog?n=50
I'm querying container image data using the Google Container Registry API.
For some reason I'm consistently getting this weird 504 error for this specific registry and I'm really not sure what's going on here.
GCP's API returns clear 429 errors when you exceed ratelimit and clear unauthorized errors when it's a permission thing so I assume it isn't one of these.
For now I'm just skipping this registry but this causes me to lose data which isn't ideal to say the least.
Any ideas why this is happening and how I can tackle this?

We recommend avoiding _catalog endpoint if possible for AR or GCR. Usually you can get better much results querying the specific info you need using the AR api (https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest)
